# Adding fields to js objects, in functional way

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, functional-programming

I have an array of objects with a set of fields in node.js. Lets say

```
let arr = [ {a:1,b:2}, {a:3,b:6}]
```

I would like to extend all objects and assign to a new variable. My naïve approach is like the following way

```
let arr2 = arr.map(x => x.c = x.a + x.b )
```

However, the arrow function returns the x.a+x.b value, instead of the `x` object, so this won't work as I hope. It also alters the `arr` in place which is very nonfunctional and confusing.

I'm relatively new to js so maybe I'm thinking wrong from the beginning. What is the idiomatic js expression for this kind of object extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write all properties from one object to another with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
const arr2 = arr.map(x => Object.assign({c: x.a + x.b}, x));
```

And maybe at some point in the future with object spread (not yet standardized):

```
const arr2 = arr.map(x => ({...x, c: x.a + x.b}));
```

Comment: Nice! Exactly what I hoped for! :D

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

```
let arr2 = arr.map(x => {
      x.c = x.a + x.b;
      return x;
});
```

Please also refer working snippet

```js
let arr = [ {a:1,b:2}, {a:3,b:6}];
let arr2 = arr.map(x => {
  return Object.assign({c : x.a + x.b},x);
});


console.log(arr);
console.log(arr2);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Sorry. This will overwrite `arr`, :(

Answer (score 1):

Although the same general idea as other answers, this might be slightly more readable:

```
arr.map(({a, b}) => ({a, b, c: a + b}))
```

Comment: mhm i like this one ^_^